# C# streaming large file through serialPort to an Arduino UNO

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port, streaming, communication

I´d like to stream a text file containing G-Code to an Arduino UNO via the serialPort.

The Arduino receives all bytes with the SerialEvent and adds it to a char array named buffer. If the buffer is full it is supposed to send an "!;" over the serial port to C#.
This works fine as I have tested it with the Serial Montior application of the Arduino IDE. But I can´t type text as fast as C# can send it :)

The C# program reads the G-Code file linewise and then sends each char in a line to the arduino. After each char I want to check if the Arduino tells me if the buffer is full. Otherwise keep streaming.

Somehow c# never notices the "!;" or even gets any Bytes to read from the Arduino while streaming. I have the feeling that the serialPort.Write() function blocks the port.

This is the Arduino Code:

```
void serialEvent()
{
  // wenn im Puffer noch platz ist
  if (buffercount < MAX_BUF)
  {
    char c = (char)Serial.read();
    buffer[buffercount++] = c;
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print("!;");
  }
}
```

The serialEvent is fired every time the Arduino receives bytes on the port.
Max_BUF has a value of 64.

This is the C# Code:

```
private void startStreaming(string Text)
{
    string[] stringSeparators;
    string Text2Stream;

    if (Text == "")
    {
        Text2Stream = File.ReadAllText(textBoxSelectFile.Text);
        stringSeparators = new string[] { "\n" };
    }
    else
    {
        stringSeparators = new string[] { "\r\n" };
        Text2Stream = Text;
    }

    string[] t2s = Text2Stream.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
    foreach (string zeile in t2s)
    {

        if (zeile.Contains(")") || zeile.Contains("("))
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Code schicken
        foreach (char c in zeile)
        {
            if (c == ' ') continue;
            serialPort.Write(c.ToString());
            if (serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                if(serialPort.ReadExisting() == "!;")
                   {
                    **wait and do smth.**
                   }
            }
        }
        serialPort.Write(";");
        addTextToLog(zeile);

    }
}
```

`serialPort.ReadExisiting()` never happens because there are never `BytesToRead`.
The ";" is for both the sign for the end of a line.
`startStreaming` is started in an asynchronous thread as `BackGroundWorker`.

Answer (score 0):

> Somehow c# never notices the "!;" or even gets any Bytes to read from the Arduino while streaming. I have the feeling that the serialPort.Write() function blocks the port.

The `Write` command is not blocking the port. The arduino is just much slower then your computer. So between these two lines:

```
serialPort.Write(c.ToString());

if (serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
```

the arduino is occupied and no data is received **yet**. Therefore `BytesToRead` is `0`. Two possibilities to solve that come right away to my mind.

1) Use the `serialPort.DataReceived` event for asynchronous processing. This will be triggered every time you receive data. Then you can react upon the received data in that event or

2) Just give the arduino some time with `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);`

```
serialPort.Write(c.ToString());
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
if (serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
```

You need to find out which is the minimum timespan to wait.

Comment: Sounds legit but while the C# application keeps streaming it never happens to receive anything. I think your answer may be right but i´m curious if it´s 100% correct because of that. If i keep streaming there is no response.

Comment: I´ve tested it with your mentioned sleep() but that doesn´t help either :( maybe i´m missing something on the arduino side ?

Comment: if I tell the Arduino to write smth to the serialPort after receiving a byte that doesn´t work too.

    char c = (char)Serial.read();

    buffer[buffercount++] = c;

    Serial.print("L");

Comment: have you tried to send the received char right away back to the computer? does this work?

Comment: On the Arduino side i´ve removed the part where it adds the char to the buffer. So it won´t do any work on it too. Then i´ve added a line where it sends the received char right back, that works like a charm. I don´t even need to add sleep in C#. Maybe something is wrong with my arduino Code... I´ll keep you updated.

Comment: @Mika sound like it, now I am curious... it looks like you never reached the else condition on arduino side. What is the value of `MAX_BUF` ? and what is the size of the `buffer`

Comment: Actually i got new intel what is causing my problems. The buffersize for the Arduino is 64 bytes. The Arduino fires the SerialEvent continous while there are bytes to read in the serial in buffer. As long as i don´t read them out it fires the event. I thought it would only fire everytime a byte is recieved at the port.
On the other hand, C# sends all bytes no matter what. Wich means if the arduino can´t keep up with the speed of C# sending bytes - every byte that is on its way to the arudino and arrives at an full serial buffer will be lost.

Comment: Okay while the arduino is processing a full command there are delays for some stepper motors. While it´s adding up those delays for the stepper motor in the function itselfe it doesn´t leave the function and so it can´t handle any other serial connection response or read. Meaning i have to replace the delay() with some timing logic.

Comment: @Mika I did not see any motor communication in your arduino code. It is still not really clear to me why the arduino did respond after you removed `buffer[buffercount++] = c;`